# Camel file component charset with more than one endpoints

Tags: character-encoding, apache-camel

when i have a route that sends data to two different file component endpoints,
where about one EP i don't really care about the encoding but about the other EP, i need to ensure a certain encoding, should i still set the charsetname in both encodings?

I'm asking because a client of ours had a problem in that area. the route receives UTF-8 and and we need to write iso-8859-1 to the file.
And now, after the whole hardware was restarted (after power-outage), we found things like "??" instead of the expected "ä".

Now, by specifying the charsetname on all file producer endpoints, we were able to solve the issue.

My actual question now is:

do you think i can now expect that the problem is solved for good?
Or shouldn't there be a relation and I would be well advised not to lean back until I 100% understand the issue.

Notes that might be helpfull:

- in addition, before writing to any of those two file endpoints, we 
  also do .convertBodyTo(byte[].class, "iso-8859-1")
- we use camel 2.16.1

Comment: Think you answered your own question...  Specifying character encoding on file endpoints should address the problem going forward.  That said, wouldn't be a bad thing to test that theory after removing the convertBodyTo(...) call, to verify that you don't need both bits.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and aggreed.
But note that the question i'm even more interested in is this:
Does the first of the endpoints not only convert what's written to disk, but also affect "downstream" endpoints?
Also, is there a "first" EP, just because i declared it first? or is the order undertermined?

Comment: Yes, the downstream endpoints will received the encoded byte array as the message flows through the route.  There are some settings in Camel (e.g. stream caching) which will change the body of the data in the exchange; avoid those and you should be fine.

Comment: thx, i'm going to try that

Comment: Just stumbled over camel multicast: https://camel.apache.org/how-to-send-the-same-message-to-multiple-endpoints.html looks like i should use it for address the problem above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, the problem was not about having two file endpoints in one pipeline.

It was about the JVM's default encoding as written here:

http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Q-about-how-to-help-the-file2-component-to-do-a-better-job-td5783381.html